# Finding an operation that satisfies a specific requirement in "lean"

Tags: function, boolean, algebra, lean

I have already define four boolean operations:

```
def bnot : bool → bool 
| tt := ff
| ff := tt 

def band : bool → bool → bool 
| tt b := b
| ff b := ff

def bor : bool → bool → bool 
| tt b := tt
| ff b := b

def is_tt : bool → Prop 
| tt := true
| ff := false
```

and now I need to define an new operation:

```
def exb  (f : bool → bool) : bool
    :=sorry,
```

then use the operations above to computer and prove the existential quantification on booleans

```
exb_ok : ∀ f : bool → bool, is_tt (exb f) ↔ ∃ x : bool, is_tt (f x) :=
begin
  sorry,
end
```

Now change the 'sorry' to the real answer.

I think may be it has

```
def exb  (f : bool → bool) : bool
    := f tt || f ff

theorem exb_ok : ∀ f : bool → bool, is_tt (exb f) ↔ ∃ x : bool, is_tt (f x) :=
begin
  assume f,
  constructor,
  dsimp[exb],
  assume h,
  existsi tt,
end
```

and I stop at this step, I do not know how to do next.
And the goals now are

```
'f : bool → bool,
 h : is_tt (f tt||f ff)
 ⊢ is_tt (f tt)
 
 f : bool → bool
 ⊢ (∃ (x : bool), is_tt (f x)) → is_tt (exb f)'
```